# Real algebraic groups and pseudo-finiteness

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

What is the relationship between pseudo-finite groups and real algebraic groups?

Could you provide an example of a pseudo-finite real algebraic group and of a non pseudo-finite one, if any?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any reasons to suspect the two might be related in any interesting way? For a trivial example, any finite (e.g. trivial) group is isomorphic to a real algebraic group and pseudofinite. On the other hand, I think most likely a "generic" real algebraic group is not pseudo-finite.

Comment: @tomasz In "Euler characteristic in semialgebraic and other o-minimal groups", Strzebonski proves that the (o-minimal) euler characteristic of a semialgebraic group plays the role of the cardinality of a finite group, so I was wondering how similar real algebraic groups are to finite groups and what first order property of finite groups fails for a generic real algebraic group.